# Change Screen resolution on EC2 Windows server 8 R2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, screen, resolution, vps

what will be the easiest way to change the resolution on Ec2 Windows server?

I am running Windows 8 R2

Any idea appreciated...:)

Comment: This question is a better fit for Super User.

Answer (score 2):

That setting comes from your client. If you are connecting over remote desktop, go to the display tab and then set the 'display configuration' to the value you want.

You many seed to select the 'show options' link first if your are opening your connection from the mstsc command.

Comment: Thanks. (I presumed you couldn't change the settings due to AWS locking it down. Tiny screen is frustrating!) On MacOSX I had to save the connection as a .rdp file, then go File > Edit a Connection to get to these settings. There's no UI during initial connection.

Comment: On OSX go to `Preferences > Display` and you'll need to reconnect to apply.

Comment: Any references to doc for this?

Answer (score 1):

Several years later, but I've been digging for this answer for at least 2 hours so I thought I'd save someone a headache.

For those of you reading this who are attempting to change the resolution as part of your Selenium Grid, but don't want to do any registry editing and cannot have an insecure solution to changing the resolution (mentioned in the linked superuser article [here](https://superuser.com/questions/414546/how-do-i-change-the-resolution-of-an-amazon-ec2-windows-machine#)), you can simply modify the test itself to use set the size of the window.

```
webDriver.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(1920, 1080);
```

While those values are hardcoded, you could conceivably set them as an environment variable on your host machine that is running the test so that you can still support multiple hosts with different window sizes.