# Increasing screen resolution for selenium test in AWS instance

Tags: selenium, amazon-ec2, bamboo

I am using bamboo to run selenium test. In bamboo, i am using elastic agents which is an aws instance - windows 2012 . By default, the screen resolution of the agent is 1024x768. I just want to increase the screen resolution.

Is it possible to increase screen resolution as part of ami creation or after starting the agent?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=148846

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20178032/change-screen-resolution-on-ec2-windows-server-8-r2

Comment: Running it in Chrome headless doesn't depend on screen resolution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround that I was able to come up with for this exact scenario --

The problem is that unless you use RDP to connect, AWS EC2 instances use the default basic graphics adapter, which has a max res of 1024x768.
Trying to set the Browser size via Selenium will **not** work, as the browser window will be automatically resized to the maximum desktop resolution size.

However, you can do this:
After your browser is opened during your test run, you can call into unmanaged code and set the browser window's size via a method in user32.dll with a flag that stops Windows from automatically resizing the browser window back to the maximum desktop resolution size.

The code is as follows (partially taken from pinvoke.net). This is a C# example, but could be reworked into some other type of solution to be called from your framework.

Within a class somewhere within your framework, place the following, and then in your code to instantiate your browser window, simply make a call to the SetBrowserLocAndSize method:

```
// Windows Interop Screen window position setter extern method
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

public static void SetBrowserLocAndSize(string windowTitle, int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    var proc = Process.GetProcesses().FirstOrDefault(p => p.MainWindowTitle.Contains(windowTitle));

    if(proc == null)
    {
        throw new NotFoundException($"Could not find a window containing a window title of '{windowTitle}'");
    }

    var hwnd = proc.MainWindowHandle;

    // See https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.setwindowpos for information on this method
    SetWindowPos(hwnd, new IntPtr(0), x, y, width, height, 0x0100 | 0x0400 | 0x0040);
}
```